# Storing user preferences for a Visual Studio custom project wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wizard, visual-studio-extensions

## Background:

I am working on a SDK that allows its users to create custom plugins for an existing product. There is a bit of boilerplate code/file copy/COM DLL registration required for the plugin integration.To ease things for the plugin developer, I have written a Visual Studio custom project template that uses a [IWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) to create a new solution, add couple of projects, generate a number of files containing the boilerplate code as well as some batch files that get executed as a post build event.

The wizard has a number of fields (such as the copyright header that needs to be inserted at the top of each generated file) that the user can edit to customize the generated code.

## The Question

I'd like to persist some of the customizations and use it across multiple runs of the wizard. I also know the usual recommended places for individual applications to store their settings is under %APPDATA%. I'd like to know if there are any other places where specifically Visual Studio extensions can store their settings or I should just treat this as an standalone application and go with the %APPDATA% folder. The reason I ask is further down the line, I like to allow the plugin developers to share these settings via VS->Tools->Import & Export Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You can use Visual Studio's [DialogPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.dialogpage.aspx) which will show up your configurations in Visual Studio's Options window. You can also use [IProfileManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.iprofilemanager.ASPX), if you do not want your preferences to show in Options window but you still want to persist them.

I have written blog post about both of these options. These posts contains complete details and code snippets.

1. [Integration with Visual Studio Options Window using custom controls](http://geekswithblogs.net/onlyutkarsh/archive/2013/06/30/integration-of-options-window-in-visual-studio-extension-with-custom.aspx)
2. [Persisting settings without using Options dialog in Visual Studio](http://geekswithblogs.net/onlyutkarsh/archive/2013/11/02/persisting-settings-without-using-options-dialog-in-visual-studio.aspx)

Comment: Since I dont have enough rep points, I am unable to upvote this answer but this is exactly what I need.